# Recursive processing of data from socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, recursion, boost

I am stuck with a problem here while processing of data coming from server using boost asio read_some().

Data format is: 83, datalength, data

Problem:

I am receiving packets from server in chunks where packets can have single data, or many data.
Also, there can be scenario where I can receive single data in 2-3 packets.
Though I have written the iterative logic for same but I was wondering if some1 can suggest Recursive logic for this type of problem.
I am not very confident in recursion,hence help would be much appreciated.

Also,another question, is maximum length if data read using boost asio read_some(), 1500 bytes?

Comment: I cannot imagine where in this scenario a recursive implementation would be helpful (or even reasonably possible..) can you elaborate on the reasons why you are looking for a recursive way?

Comment: @JackWhite : Well !! , I just thought it would be easier to implement using recursion as Data is being processed again and again.
As my logic has through iterative method has become very complex, hence was looking to simplify it. Can it be done?

Comment: Smash the data into a queue, monitor the validity of the data within the queue, when you know it is good, pull it out and process it.

Comment: when you say recursive, are you maybe talking about the asynchronous part of asio, i.e. [boost::asio::async_read()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) ?

Comment: @PhilWilliams : I am already pushing all the coming data into vector, and processing it but as I mentioned logic of processing has become little cumbersome, hence was looking for a easy way to do same.

Comment: @JackWhite: I am currently reading data using boost::asio read_some(),
which gives me data in chunk of 1500 bytes always,


for (;;)
{
   length=m_Socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_RecieveBuffer),e);
}

Is there a better way to read data from socket?
As per my requirement I am sending some command and response from server contains notify+response,

So basically, packet contains both data (in data format which I mentioned )

Answer (score 1):

As per comments I think recursion wouldn't be a good choice here.I got to stick with my iterative method.
Thanks every1 for prompt reply/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

split the thing into 2 buffers, one for raw data, and a queue for complete packets.
 something link this:

```
while(true) {
    receive data from socket
    append data to sendBuffer
    while( sendbuffer contains a complete packet) {
        move packet to packetQueue();
        removePacket from sendbuffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am already doing something similar to what you suggested.Anyway thanks for suggestion.